# Decrypt Kerberos Token

Tags: authentication, iis, kerberos

We have existing systems in place,based on existing environments we are setting up new environment.
In one of the service we are using Kerberos authentication.When we requesting a service on ServerA it generates Kerberos token and adds to Authorization header and request is passed to ServerB, But in case of new environment we are getting 401.2.5 error in IIS. We believe that SPNs and KDC are in place.
I have validated token with existing environment tokens and are similar structure.

- Is there a way to decrypt the Kerberos token so that i can validate
  what data it contains.
- What are other possibilities that i will need to check.

Comment: Can you verify if you are getting kerberos token and not the ntlm token? While requesting a ticket from server A,  please verify the headers on response/request while negotiating. It should be 'Negotiate' and not 'NTLM' or anything else.

Comment: Yes its a Kerberos token it starts with YIIF...

Comment: any progress with this?